# Error of not registered Autofac.Extras.NLog.ILogger only with RegisterAggregateService

Tags: autofac

Getting error of not registered ILogger only when it is inside of RegisterAggregateService

```
[ComponentNotRegisteredException: The requested service 'Autofac.Extras.NLog.ILogger' has not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency.]
   Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +304
   Autofac.Extras.AggregateService.ResolvingInterceptor.SetupInvocationMap(Type interfaceType) +527
   Autofac.Extras.AggregateService.AggregateServiceGenerator.CreateInstance(Type interfaceType, IComponentContext context) +99
   Autofac.Builder.<>c__DisplayClass1`1.<ForDelegate>b__0(IComponentContext c, IEnumerable`1 p) +15
   Autofac.Core.Activators.Delegate.DelegateActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +32
   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters) +86
   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute() +62
   Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +170
   Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ConstructorParameterBinding.Instantiate() +124
   Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +266
   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters) +86
   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute() +62
   Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +170
   Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +109
   Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance) +124
   Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptionalService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +70
   Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptional(IComponentContext context, Type serviceType) +122
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +59
```

> ```
> builder.RegisterModule<NLogModule>();
> builder.RegisterModule(new AutofacWebTypesModule());
> builder.RegisterAggregateService<ImportController.IImportControllerDep>();
> ```

Answer (score 6):

use ILogger from Autofac.Extras.NLog  - not from NLog

Comment: This should really be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Prune this should really be marked as the answer because it was for me and Im sure many others

Answer (score 0):

Use `SimpleNLogModule` to resolving from service locator
https://github.com/ziyasal/Autofac.Extras.NLog#register-simplenlogmodule-to-autofac

`builder.RegisterModule<SimpleNLogModule>();
_logger = serviceLocator.Resolve<ILogger>();`

Comment: Was the SimpleNLogModule removed at some point?  I'm using version 4.0.0 of Autofac.Extras.NLog and it has no reference to that class.